# My .htaccess redirect that was created to stop a redirect is only partially working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a weird issue that is making my site redirect from example.org to example.org/forums/ and also from http://example.org to example.org/forus/

To fix this I made a redirect in htaccess using the below code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The only thing the redirect did was add a 'www' to the url and still forwards to /forums/.  It now goes from example.org to www.example.org/forums/

Is there away to make it only go to www.example.org and stropping any directory from being added? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: r=301 is cached by browser, check with incognito mode first, and see result the same

Comment: Checked in incognito and it is still there.

Comment: then the problem is not htaccess, check your index page and see any redirect to `/forums`